# toprule and midrule not covering whole table

Tags: tables

I was wondering why my `\toprule` and `\midrule` does not make lines to the end of the table. The last column is not included by `\toprule` and `\midrule`. Does someone of you know why?

By using the following code I get a horizontal line that covers every column but the last one.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} %Doku: "scrguide"

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % Eingabekodierung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % Fontkodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    % deutsche Sprachenunterstützung; Doku: "gerdoc"

\usepackage{float}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\sffamily\bfseries} % kleinere Beschriftungen
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}                      % --''--
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}  % Zeilenabstand im Text
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}     % Zeilenabstand in mehrzeiligen Formeln und Tabellen


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{threeparttablex}

\usepackage{tabularx, siunitx,booktabs}


\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H]
\scriptsize
\caption{Faktorladungsstruktur und Kommunalitäten der EFA mit Hauptachsenlösung und Oblimin-Rotation} 
\label{tab:efa} 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
%{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
%\scalebox{0.65}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1.8cm}
        l
        X*{9}{S[table-format=2.2]}
    c}      
    \toprule
Items   &Dimension laut Manual& \multicolumn{9}{c}{Faktorladungen} & {Kommunalität} \\ \cmidrule(r){3-11} \cmidrule(l){12-12}
    & & {1} & {2}  & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9}&{$h^2$}\\ \midrule
    TICS 54 &\textbf{UEBE} &  .89 &  & &  &&&&&&0.77\\
    TICS 44 &\textbf{UEBE} & .87&   & & & &&&&&0.78\\
    TICS 50 &\textbf{UEBE} &.84&   & & & &&&&&0.78\\
    TICS 17 &\textbf{UEBE} &.75&   & & & &&&&&0.70\\
    TICS 38 &\textbf{UEBE} &.70&   & & & &&&&&0.66\\
    TICS 4  & \textbf{UEBE} &.57&   & & & &&&&-.34&0.61\\
    TICS 27 &\textbf{UEBE} &.41&   & & & &&&&.28&0.47\\
    TICS 24 &UEFO &.39&   & & & &&.38&&&0.58\\
    TICS 1  &\textbf{UEBE} &.35&   &.26 & & &&&&&0.37\\
    TICS 7  &SOUE  &.35&   & & & &&-.28&&&0.49\\ \midrule
    TICS 23 &\textbf{ERDR} & &  .82 & & & &&&&&0.68\\
    TICS 40 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .69 & & & &&&&&0.61\\
    TICS 14 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .57 & & & &&&&&0.56\\
    TICS 22 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .57 & & & &&&&&0.58\\
    TICS 8  &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .49 & & & &&&&&0.51\\
    TICS 49 &SOUE& &  .45 & & & &&&&.28&0.47\\
    TICS 43 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .44 & & & &&&&&0.45\\
    TICS 39 &SOUE& &  .43 & & &.27 &&&&&0.54\\
    TICS 32 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .39 &.33 & & &&&&&0.61\\
    TICS 30 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .38 & & .26& &&&&&0.44\\ \midrule
    TICS 31 &\textbf{MANG}& &      & .86& & &&&&&0.77\\
    TICS 46 &\textbf{MANG}& &      & .77& & &&&&&0.65\\
    TICS 18 &\textbf{MANG}& &      & .76& & &&&&&0.68\\
    TICS 2  &\textbf{MANG}& &       & .70& & &&&&&0.55\\
    TICS 5  &UNZU& &      & .35& & &&&.34&-.26&0.52\\
    TICS 48 &UNZU & &      & .31& & &&&&.26&0.37\\
    TICS 21 &UNZU & &      & .30& &.25 &&&&&0.56\\ \midrule
    TICS 33&\textbf{SOZS }& &      &    & .69& &&&&&0.54\\
    TICS 52&\textbf{SOZS} & &      &    & .68& &&&&&0.54\\
    TICS 45&\textbf{SOZS} & &      &    & .68& &&&&&0.55\\
    TICS 15&\textbf{SOZS} & &      &    & .56& &&&&&0.56\\
    TICS 6&\textbf{SOZS }& &      &     & .52& &&&&&0.48\\
    TICS 26&\textbf{SOZS} & &      &    & .52& &&&&&0.53\\
    TICS 37&UNZU & &      &    & .43& &&.28&&&0.40\\
    TICS 57&SOUE & &      &    & .36& &&&&&0.48\\
    TICS 12&ERDR & & .26  &    & .29& &&&&-.26&0.57\\ \midrule
    TICS 36&\textbf{SORG} & &      &    &    & .61 &&&&&0.72\\
    TICS 25&\textbf{SORG} & &      &    &    & .59 &&&&&0.70\\
    TICS 16&\textbf{SORG} & &      &    &    & .57 &&&&&0.66\\
    TICS 9&\textbf{SORG}  & &  .26 &    &    & .52 &&&&&0.59\\
    TICS 19&SOUE & &      &    &    & .51 &&&&&0.59\\
    TICS 11&SOZI & &      &    &    & .43 &.39&&&&0.67\\
    TICS 28&SOUE & &   .27&    &    & .37 &&&&&0.47\\ \midrule
    TICS 42&\textbf{SOZI} & &      &    &    &     &.79&&&&0.67\\
    TICS 51&\textbf{SOZI }& &      &    &    &     &.74&&&&0.53\\
    TICS 56&\textbf{SOZI} & &      &    &    &     &.51&&&&0.48\\
    TICS 29&\textbf{SOZI}& &      &    &    &  .29&.45&&&&0.54\\
    TICS 41&UNZU & &      &    & .33&     &.40&&&&0.38\\
    TICS 34&\textbf{SOZI}& &      &    & .27&     &.36&&&&0.56\\ \midrule
    TICS 55&\textbf{UEFO} & &      &    &    &     &   &.62&&&0.54\\
    TICS 35&\textbf{UEFO} & &      &    &    &     &   &.60&&&0.58\\
    TICS 20&\textbf{UEFO} & &      &    &    &     &   &.52&&&0.47\\
    TICS 47&\textbf{UEFO}& &      &    &    &  .28&   &.44&&&0.57\\
    TICS 3&\textbf{UEFO}  & &      &    &    &     &   &.39&&-.34&0.44\\ \midrule
    TICS 10&\textbf{UNZU} & &      &    &    &     &   &   &.60&&0.49\\
    TICS 13&\textbf{UNZU} & &      &    &    &     &   &   &.51&&0.54\\
    TICS 53&\textbf{UNZU} & &      &    &    &     &   &   &.33&.29&0.58\\
    \midrule 
    Varianzaufklärung in \%       &    & 10 &8 &8 &8 &7 &6 &5 &3 &2& \\
    Kumulative Varianzaufklärung in \%&&10  &18&26&33&41&46&51&54&56&{$\sum$ = 56}\\
    %Eigenwerte &&&&&\\ 
    \bottomrule
    %\tiny Hinweis: Zur besseren Übersicht wurden nur
    % Faktorladungen > |0.25| abgebildet.
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tablenotes}
    \item Hinweis: Analog zur Originalfassung wurden nur Faktorladungen > |0.25| abgebildet. Fettgedruckte Dimensionsnamen markieren die richtige Zuordnung laut Manual.
    \end{tablenotes}
    
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: your rules are the specified with of the table (`\textwidth)` but your table content is far too wide, tex reports `Overfull \hbox (126.14513pt too wide) in alignment at lines 104--104`

Comment: given the impossible constraints that you have set, tabularx gives up and warns `Package tabularx Warning: X Columns too narrow (table too wide)`  The table is not intended to be usable in such a situation.

Comment: @jsbibra no that would generate an error, there are no errors here just overfull box warnings. 13 columns are defined.

Comment: Apart from bing wider than the textwidth, your table is also taller than the textheight. (see the warning "Overfull \vbox (276.38391pt too high) ") To overcome this and to allow a pagebrak within the table, you could combine `threeparrtablex` with `xltabular`.

Answer (score 3):

Your table is to huge that can be fit on one page. You should consider to write multipage table. For example by using `xtabular` package, which is combination of `longtable` and `tabularx` pakages:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} %Doku: "scrguide"
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % Fontkodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    % deutsche Sprachenunterstützung; Doku: "gerdoc"


\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\sffamily\bfseries} % kleinere Beschriftungen
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}                      % --''--
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}  % Zeilenabstand im Text


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell, multirow, xltabular}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex} % <--- for \note, \source
\renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}   % new
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \sisetup{detect-weight,
             mode=text}
    \footnotesize
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.9}
\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont
\note{
Analog zur Originalfassung wurden nur Faktorladungen > |0.25| abgebildet. Fettgedruckte Dimensionsnamen markieren die richtige Zuordnung laut Manual.
    }
    \end{TableNotes}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} X X
                            *{10}{S[table-format=1.2]}
                              @{}}
\caption{Faktorladungsstruktur und Kommunalitäten der EFA mit Hauptachsenlösung und Oblimin-Rotation}
\label{tab:efa} \\
    \toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{Items}
    & \multirow{2.4}{*}{\thead{Dimension\\ laut\\ Manual}}
            & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Faktorladungen} & {Kommunalität} \\ \cmidrule(r){3-11} \cmidrule(l){12-12}
    & & {1} & {2}  & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9}&{$h^2$}\\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Faktorladungsstruktur und Kommunalitäten der EFA mit Hauptachsenlösung und Oblimin-Rotation (cont.)}     \\
    \toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{Items}
    & \multirow{2.4}{*}{\thead{Dimension\\ laut\\ Manual}}
            & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Faktorladungen} & {Kommunalität} \\ \cmidrule(r){3-11} \cmidrule(l){12-12}
    & & {1} & {2}  & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9}&{$h^2$}\\ \midrule
\endhead
    \multicolumn{12}{r}{\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{12}{@{} l}{Varianz.: Varianzaufklärung;}\\
    \insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
    TICS 54 &\textbf{UEBE} &  .89 &  & &  &&&&&&0.77\\
    TICS 44 &\textbf{UEBE} & .87&   & & & &&&&&0.78\\
    TICS 50 &\textbf{UEBE} &.84&   & & & &&&&&0.78\\
    TICS 17 &\textbf{UEBE} &.75&   & & & &&&&&0.70\\
    TICS 38 &\textbf{UEBE} &.70&   & & & &&&&&0.66\\
    TICS 4  & \textbf{UEBE} &.57&   & & & &&&&-.34&0.61\\
    TICS 27 &\textbf{UEBE} &.41&   & & & &&&&.28&0.47\\
    TICS 24 &UEFO &.39&   & & & &&.38&&&0.58\\
    TICS 1  &\textbf{UEBE} &.35&   &.26 & & &&&&&0.37\\
    TICS 7  &SOUE  &.35&   & & & &&-.28&&&0.49\\ \midrule
    TICS 23 &\textbf{ERDR} & &  .82 & & & &&&&&0.68\\
    TICS 40 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .69 & & & &&&&&0.61\\
    TICS 14 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .57 & & & &&&&&0.56\\
    TICS 22 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .57 & & & &&&&&0.58\\
    TICS 8  &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .49 & & & &&&&&0.51\\
    TICS 49 &SOUE& &  .45 & & & &&&&.28&0.47\\
    TICS 43 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .44 & & & &&&&&0.45\\
    TICS 39 &SOUE& &  .43 & & &.27 &&&&&0.54\\
    TICS 32 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .39 &.33 & & &&&&&0.61\\
    TICS 30 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .38 & & .26& &&&&&0.44\\ \midrule
    TICS 31 &\textbf{MANG}& &      & .86& & &&&&&0.77\\
    TICS 46 &\textbf{MANG}& &      & .77& & &&&&&0.65\\
    TICS 18 &\textbf{MANG}& &      & .76& & &&&&&0.68\\
    TICS 2  &\textbf{MANG}& &       & .70& & &&&&&0.55\\
    TICS 5  &UNZU& &      & .35& & &&&.34&-.26&0.52\\
    TICS 48 &UNZU & &      & .31& & &&&&.26&0.37\\
    TICS 21 &UNZU & &      & .30& &.25 &&&&&0.56\\ \midrule
    TICS 33 &\textbf{SOZS }& &      &    & .69& &&&&&0.54\\
    TICS 52 &\textbf{SOZS} & &      &    & .68& &&&&&0.54\\
    TICS 45 &\textbf{SOZS} & &      &    & .68& &&&&&0.55\\
    TICS 15 &\textbf{SOZS} & &      &    & .56& &&&&&0.56\\
    TICS 6  &\textbf{SOZS }& &      &     & .52& &&&&&0.48\\
    TICS 26 &\textbf{SOZS} & &      &    & .52& &&&&&0.53\\
    TICS 37 &UNZU & &      &    & .43& &&.28&&&0.40\\
    TICS 57 &SOUE & &      &    & .36& &&&&&0.48\\
    TICS 12 &ERDR & & .26  &    & .29& &&&&-.26&0.57\\
        \midrule
        \pagebreak
    TICS 36 &\textbf{SORG} & &      &    &    & .61 &&&&&0.72\\
    TICS 25 &\textbf{SORG} & &      &    &    & .59 &&&&&0.70\\
    TICS 16 &\textbf{SORG} & &      &    &    & .57 &&&&&0.66\\
    TICS 9  &\textbf{SORG}  & &  .26 &    &    & .52 &&&&&0.59\\
    TICS 19 &SOUE & &      &    &    & .51 &&&&&0.59\\
    TICS 11 &SOZI & &      &    &    & .43 &.39&&&&0.67\\
    TICS 28 &SOUE & &   .27&    &    & .37 &&&&&0.47\\ \midrule
    TICS 42 &\textbf{SOZI} & &      &    &    &     &.79&&&&0.67\\
    TICS 51 &\textbf{SOZI }& &      &    &    &     &.74&&&&0.53\\
    TICS 56 &\textbf{SOZI} & &      &    &    &     &.51&&&&0.48\\
    TICS 29 &\textbf{SOZI}& &      &    &    &  .29&.45&&&&0.54\\
    TICS 41 &UNZU & &      &    & .33&     &.40&&&&0.38\\
    TICS 34 &\textbf{SOZI}& &      &    & .27&     &.36&&&&0.56\\ \midrule
    TICS 55 &\textbf{UEFO} & &      &    &    &     &   &.62&&&0.54\\
    TICS 35 &\textbf{UEFO} & &      &    &    &     &   &.60&&&0.58\\
    TICS 20 &\textbf{UEFO} & &      &    &    &     &   &.52&&&0.47\\
    TICS 47 &\textbf{UEFO}& &      &    &    &  .28&   &.44&&&0.57\\
    TICS 3  &\textbf{UEFO}  & &      &    &    &     &   &.39&&-.34&0.44\\ \midrule
    TICS 10 &\textbf{UNZU} & &      &    &    &     &   &   &.60&&0.49\\
    TICS 13 &\textbf{UNZU} & &      &    &    &     &   &   &.51&&0.54\\
    TICS 53 &\textbf{UNZU} & &      &    &    &     &   &   &.33&.29&0.58\\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{} l @{}}{Varianz. in \%}
                           & 10 &8 &8 &8 &7 &6 &5 &3 &2& \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{} l @{}}{Kumulative Varianz. in \%}
                           &\B 10 &\B 18 &\B 26 &\B 33 &\B 41
                           &\B 46 &\B 51 &\B 54 &\B 56 & {$\sum = \mathbf{56}$}\\
\end{xltabular}

\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

After (at least) two compilation above MWE produce:

[image]

**Addendum:**
After your comment below, it become unclear, what actually is your problem. Guesing, that you like to have inconsistent writing of numbers in your table (mostly without leading zeros, minus sign before decimal point, ...), below is such version of your table.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} %Doku: "scrguide"
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % Fontkodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    % deutsche Sprachenunterstützung; Doku: "gerdoc"


\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\sffamily\bfseries} % kleinere Beschriftungen
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}                      % --''--
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}  % Zeilenabstand im Text


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell, multirow, xltabular}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex} % <--- for \note, \source
\renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}   % new
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \begin{ThreePartTable}
\sisetup{add-integer-zero=false,
         detect-weight,
         mode=text}
\small
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}
    
\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont
\note{
Analog zur Originalfassung wurden nur Faktorladungen > |0.25| abgebildet. Fettgedruckte Dimensionsnamen markieren die richtige Zuordnung laut Manual.\\

\textbf{Legende:}\\
Var.: Varianzaufklärung;\quad
Kum. Var.: Kumulative Varianzaufklärung
    }
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} l 
                                  X
                             *{6}{S[table-format=0.2]}
                                  S[table-format=1.2]
                                  S[table-format=0.2]
                                  S[table-format=1.2]
                                  S[table-format=1.2]
                              @{}}
\caption{Faktorladungsstruktur und Kommunalitäten der EFA mit Hauptachsenlösung und Oblimin-Rotation}
\label{tab:efa} \\
    \toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{Items}
    & \multirow{2.4}{*}{\thead{Dimension\\ laut\\ Manual}}
            & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Faktorladungen} & {Kommunalität} \\ \cmidrule(r){3-11} \cmidrule(l){12-12}
    & & {1} & {2}  & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9}&{$h^2$}\\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Faktorladungsstruktur und Kommunalitäten der EFA mit Hauptachsenlösung und Oblimin-Rotation (cont.)}     \\
    \toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{Items}
    & \multirow{2.4}{*}{\thead{Dimension\\ laut\\ Manual}}
            & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Faktorladungen} & {Kommunalität} \\ \cmidrule(r){3-11} \cmidrule(l){12-12}
    & & {1} & {2}  & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9}&{$h^2$}\\ \midrule
\endhead
    \multicolumn{12}{r}{\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
    TICS 54 &\textbf{UEBE}  &.89 &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.77\\
    TICS 44 &\textbf{UEBE}  &.87 &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.78\\
    TICS 50 &\textbf{UEBE}  &.84 &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.78\\
    TICS 17 &\textbf{UEBE}  &.75 &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.70\\
    TICS 38 &\textbf{UEBE}  &.70 &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.66\\
    TICS 4  &\textbf{UEBE}  &.57 &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &-.34&0.61\\
    TICS 27 &\textbf{UEBE}  &.41 &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &.28 &0.47\\
    TICS 24 &UEFO           &.39 &    &    &    &    &    & .38&    &    &0.58\\
    TICS 1  &\textbf{UEBE}  &.35 &    &.26 &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.37\\
    TICS 7  &SOUE           &.35 &    &    &    &    &    &-.28&    &    &0.49\\ \midrule
    TICS 23 &\textbf{ERDR}  &    &.82 &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.68\\
    TICS 40 &\textbf{ERDR}  &    &.69 &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.61\\
    TICS 14 &\textbf{ERDR}  &    &.57 &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.56\\
    TICS 22 &\textbf{ERDR}  &    &.57 &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.58\\
    TICS 8  &\textbf{ERDR}  &    &.49 &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.51\\
    TICS 49 &SOUE           &    &.45 &    &    &    &    &    &    &.28 &0.47\\
    TICS 43 &\textbf{ERDR}  &    &.44 &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.45\\
    TICS 39 &SOUE           &    &.43 &    &    &.27 &    &    &    &    &0.54\\
    TICS 32 &\textbf{ERDR}  &    &.39 &.33 &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.61\\
    TICS 30 &\textbf{ERDR}  &    &.38 &    &.26 &    &    &    &    &    &0.44\\ \midrule
    TICS 31 &\textbf{MANG}  &    &    &.86 &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.77\\
    TICS 46 &\textbf{MANG}  &    &    &.77 &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.65\\
    TICS 18 &\textbf{MANG}  &    &    &.76 &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.68\\
    TICS 2  &\textbf{MANG}  &    &    &.70 &    &    &    &    &    &    &0.55\\
    TICS 5  &UNZU           &    &    &.35 &    &    &    &    &.34 &-.26&0.52\\
    TICS 48 &UNZU           &    &    &.31 &    &    &    &    &    &.26 &0.37\\
    TICS 21 &UNZU           &    &    &.30 &    &.25 &    &    &    &    &0.56\\ \midrule
    TICS 33 &\textbf{SOZS}  &    &    &    &.69 &    &    &    &    &    &0.54\\
    TICS 52 &\textbf{SOZS}  &    &    &    &.68 &    &    &    &    &    &0.54\\
    TICS 45 &\textbf{SOZS}  &    &    &    &.68 &    &    &    &    &    &0.55\\
    TICS 15 &\textbf{SOZS}  &    &    &    &.56 &    &    &    &    &    &0.56\\
    TICS 6  &\textbf{SOZS}  &    &    &    &.52 &    &    &    &    &    &0.48\\
    TICS 26 &\textbf{SOZS}  &    &    &    &.52 &    &    &    &    &    &0.53\\
    TICS 37 &UNZU           &    &    &    &.43 &    &    &.28 &    &    &0.40\\
    TICS 57 &SOUE           &    &    &    &.36 &    &    &    &    &    &0.48\\
    TICS 12 &ERDR           &    &.26 &    &.29 &    &    &    &    &-.26&0.57\\
        \midrule
        \pagebreak
    TICS 36 &\textbf{SORG}  &    &    &    &    &.61 &    &    &    &    &0.72\\
    TICS 25 &\textbf{SORG}  &    &    &    &    &.59 &    &    &    &    &0.70\\
    TICS 16 &\textbf{SORG}  &    &    &    &    &.57 &    &    &    &    &0.66\\
    TICS 9  &\textbf{SORG}  &    &.26 &    &    &.52 &    &    &    &    &0.59\\
    TICS 19 &SOUE           &    &    &    &    &.51 &    &    &    &    &0.59\\
    TICS 11 &SOZI           &    &    &    &    &.43 &.39 &    &    &    &0.67\\
    TICS 28 &SOUE           &    &.27 &    &    &.37 &    &    &    &    &0.47\\ \midrule
    TICS 42 &\textbf{SOZI}  &    &    &    &    &    &.79 &    &    &    &0.67\\
    TICS 51 &\textbf{SOZI}  &    &    &    &    &    &.74 &    &    &    &0.53\\
    TICS 56 &\textbf{SOZI}  &    &    &    &    &    &.51 &    &    &    &0.48\\
    TICS 29 &\textbf{SOZI}  &    &    &    &    &.29 &.45 &    &    &    &0.54\\
    TICS 41 &UNZU           &    &    &    &.33 &    &.40 &    &    &    &0.38\\
    TICS 34 &\textbf{SOZI}  &    &    &    &.27 &    &.36 &    &    &    &0.56\\ \midrule
    TICS 55 &\textbf{UEFO}  &    &    &    &    &    &    &.62 &    &    &0.54\\
    TICS 35 &\textbf{UEFO}  &    &    &    &    &    &    &.60 &    &    &0.58\\
    TICS 20 &\textbf{UEFO}  &    &    &    &    &    &    &.52 &    &    &0.47\\
    TICS 47 &\textbf{UEFO}  &    &    &    &    &.28 &    &.44 &    &    &0.57\\
    TICS 3  &\textbf{UEFO}  &    &    &    &    &    &    &.39 &    &-.34&0.44\\ \midrule
    TICS 10 &\textbf{UNZU}  &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &.60 &    &0.49\\
    TICS 13 &\textbf{UNZU}  &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &.51 &    &0.54\\
    TICS 53 &\textbf{UNZU}  &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &.33 &.29 &0.58\\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{} l @{}}{Var. in \%}
                           & 10  &8   &8   &8   &7   &6   &5   &3   &2   & \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{} l @{}}{Kum. Var. in \%}
                           &\B 10 &\B 18 &\B 26 &\B 33 &\B 41
                           &\B 46 &\B 51 &\B 54 &\B 56 & {$\sum = \mathbf{56}$}\\
\end{xltabular}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am not able to compile the code.  I get the error message `Undefined control sequence. \end{xltabular}`. I had problems installing the xltabular package but when I open the miktex console as an admin I can see that the package was installed with today's date. 
I don't think that it really has worked out but I don't know why since I am pretty new to LaTex. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. I have to present the table in due time so I do not really have the time investigate why the packages won't load as they should. 
I have edited my code above an the table looks somewhat acceptable now. My only problem is that the numbers from the first column do not include  the zeros (0) as in the other columns and that the numbers 1--9 are not equally spaced.  
I would be very thankful for any kind of hints.

Comment: @Claudia, sorry, but now your question become unclear. What is the problem in your table? BTW, you receive two similar answer, which solve problem about rules, i.e. = how to fit your table in  text width. Beside this alo make you avare, that your table is so long that it need to be break to two page.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a bit overfull but fits on the page, you could consider a multi-page layout or, since there are so many empty cells and so much white space within the table perhaps you could present the data in a different format using a more compact layout. (Beware I truncated some headings I leave you to revise the wording again)

[image]

```
    \documentclass[draft,paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} %Doku: "scrguide"

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % Eingabekodierung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % Fontkodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    % deutsche Sprachenunterstützung; Doku: "gerdoc"

\usepackage{float}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\sffamily\bfseries} % kleinere Beschriftungen
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}                      % --''--
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}  % Zeilenabstand im Text
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}     % Zeilenabstand in mehrzeiligen Formeln und Tabellen


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{threeparttablex}

\usepackage{tabularx, siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H]
\vspace{-2\baselineskip}
      \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.7}
\scriptsize
\caption{Faktorladungsstruktur und Kommunalitäten der EFA mit Hauptachsenlösung und Oblimin-Rotation} 
\label{tab:efa} 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
%{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
%\scalebox{0.65}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l
        l
        X*{9}{S[table-format=2.2]}
    @{}}      
    \toprule
Items   &Dimension& \multicolumn{9}{c}{Faktorladungen} & {Kommunalität} \\ \cmidrule(r){3-11} \cmidrule(l){12-12}
    & & {1} & {2}  & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9}&{$h^2$}\\ \midrule
    TICS 54 &\textbf{UEBE} &  .89 &  & &  &&&&&&0.77\\
    TICS 44 &\textbf{UEBE} & .87&   & & & &&&&&0.78\\
    TICS 50 &\textbf{UEBE} &.84&   & & & &&&&&0.78\\
    TICS 17 &\textbf{UEBE} &.75&   & & & &&&&&0.70\\
    TICS 38 &\textbf{UEBE} &.70&   & & & &&&&&0.66\\
    TICS 4  & \textbf{UEBE} &.57&   & & & &&&&-.34&0.61\\
    TICS 27 &\textbf{UEBE} &.41&   & & & &&&&.28&0.47\\
    TICS 24 &UEFO &.39&   & & & &&.38&&&0.58\\
    TICS 1  &\textbf{UEBE} &.35&   &.26 & & &&&&&0.37\\
    TICS 7  &SOUE  &.35&   & & & &&-.28&&&0.49\\ \midrule
    TICS 23 &\textbf{ERDR} & &  .82 & & & &&&&&0.68\\
    TICS 40 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .69 & & & &&&&&0.61\\
    TICS 14 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .57 & & & &&&&&0.56\\
    TICS 22 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .57 & & & &&&&&0.58\\
    TICS 8  &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .49 & & & &&&&&0.51\\
    TICS 49 &SOUE& &  .45 & & & &&&&.28&0.47\\
    TICS 43 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .44 & & & &&&&&0.45\\
    TICS 39 &SOUE& &  .43 & & &.27 &&&&&0.54\\
    TICS 32 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .39 &.33 & & &&&&&0.61\\
    TICS 30 &\textbf{ERDR}& &  .38 & & .26& &&&&&0.44\\ \midrule
    TICS 31 &\textbf{MANG}& &      & .86& & &&&&&0.77\\
    TICS 46 &\textbf{MANG}& &      & .77& & &&&&&0.65\\
    TICS 18 &\textbf{MANG}& &      & .76& & &&&&&0.68\\
    TICS 2  &\textbf{MANG}& &       & .70& & &&&&&0.55\\
    TICS 5  &UNZU& &      & .35& & &&&.34&-.26&0.52\\
    TICS 48 &UNZU & &      & .31& & &&&&.26&0.37\\
    TICS 21 &UNZU & &      & .30& &.25 &&&&&0.56\\ \midrule
    TICS 33&\textbf{SOZS }& &      &    & .69& &&&&&0.54\\
    TICS 52&\textbf{SOZS} & &      &    & .68& &&&&&0.54\\
    TICS 45&\textbf{SOZS} & &      &    & .68& &&&&&0.55\\
    TICS 15&\textbf{SOZS} & &      &    & .56& &&&&&0.56\\
    TICS 6&\textbf{SOZS }& &      &     & .52& &&&&&0.48\\
    TICS 26&\textbf{SOZS} & &      &    & .52& &&&&&0.53\\
    TICS 37&UNZU & &      &    & .43& &&.28&&&0.40\\
    TICS 57&SOUE & &      &    & .36& &&&&&0.48\\
    TICS 12&ERDR & & .26  &    & .29& &&&&-.26&0.57\\ \midrule
    TICS 36&\textbf{SORG} & &      &    &    & .61 &&&&&0.72\\
    TICS 25&\textbf{SORG} & &      &    &    & .59 &&&&&0.70\\
    TICS 16&\textbf{SORG} & &      &    &    & .57 &&&&&0.66\\
    TICS 9&\textbf{SORG}  & &  .26 &    &    & .52 &&&&&0.59\\
    TICS 19&SOUE & &      &    &    & .51 &&&&&0.59\\
    TICS 11&SOZI & &      &    &    & .43 &.39&&&&0.67\\
    TICS 28&SOUE & &   .27&    &    & .37 &&&&&0.47\\ \midrule
    TICS 42&\textbf{SOZI} & &      &    &    &     &.79&&&&0.67\\
    TICS 51&\textbf{SOZI }& &      &    &    &     &.74&&&&0.53\\
    TICS 56&\textbf{SOZI} & &      &    &    &     &.51&&&&0.48\\
    TICS 29&\textbf{SOZI}& &      &    &    &  .29&.45&&&&0.54\\
    TICS 41&UNZU & &      &    & .33&     &.40&&&&0.38\\
    TICS 34&\textbf{SOZI}& &      &    & .27&     &.36&&&&0.56\\ \midrule
    TICS 55&\textbf{UEFO} & &      &    &    &     &   &.62&&&0.54\\
    TICS 35&\textbf{UEFO} & &      &    &    &     &   &.60&&&0.58\\
    TICS 20&\textbf{UEFO} & &      &    &    &     &   &.52&&&0.47\\
    TICS 47&\textbf{UEFO}& &      &    &    &  .28&   &.44&&&0.57\\
    TICS 3&\textbf{UEFO}  & &      &    &    &     &   &.39&&-.34&0.44\\ \midrule
    TICS 10&\textbf{UNZU} & &      &    &    &     &   &   &.60&&0.49\\
    TICS 13&\textbf{UNZU} & &      &    &    &     &   &   &.51&&0.54\\
    TICS 53&\textbf{UNZU} & &      &    &    &     &   &   &.33&.29&0.58\\
    \midrule 
   \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Varianz}           & 10 &8 &8 &8 &7 &6 &5 &3 &2& \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Kumulative} &10  &18&26&33&41&46&51&54&56&{$\sum$ = 56}\\
    %Eigenwerte &&&&&\\ 
    \bottomrule
    %\tiny Hinweis: Zur besseren Übersicht wurden nur
    % Faktorladungen > |0.25| abgebildet.
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tablenotes}
    \item Hinweis: Analog zur Originalfassung wurden nur Faktorladungen > |0.25| abgebildet. Fettgedruckte Dimensionsnamen markieren die richtige Zuordnung laut Manual.
    \end{tablenotes}
    
\end{table}


\end{document}
```